# Factory Girl: How to set up a has_many/through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bdd, factory-bot

I've been struggling with setting up a `has_many/through` relationship using Factory Girl.

I have the following models:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_details, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :details, :through => :job_details
end

class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_details, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :jobs, :through => :job_details
end

class JobDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :job_id, :detail_id
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :detail
end
```

My Factory:

```
factory :job do
  association     :tenant
  title           { Faker::Company.catch_phrase }
  company         { Faker::Company.name }
  company_url     { Faker::Internet.domain_name }
  purchaser_email { Faker::Internet.email }
  description     { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(3) }
  how_to_apply    { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  location        "New York, NY"
end

factory :detail do
  association :detail_type <--another Factory not show here
  description "Full Time"
end

factory :job_detail do
  association :job
  association :detail
end
```

What I want is for my job factory to be created with a default `Detail` of "Full Time".

I've been trying to follow this, but have not had any luck:
[FactoryGirl Has Many through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650204/factorygirl-has-many-through)

I'm not sure how the `after_create` should be used to attach the Detail via JobDetail.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try something like this. You want to build a `detail` object and append it to the job's detail association. When you use `after_create`, the created job will be yielded to the block. So you can use FactoryGirl to create a detail object, and add it to that job's details directly.

```
factory :job do
  ...

  after_create do |job|
    job.details << FactoryGirl.create(:detail)
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked great thank you.  One question - adding the after_create works, but it responds with `DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `detail_id'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc.`  any ideas?

Comment: I know this is old, but in FactoryGirl you now use callbacks with the format `after(:create)` instead of `after_create` The rest of the answer should still work without error.

Comment: more info on `after(:create)` callbacks: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/get-your-callbacks-on-with-factory-girl-3-3

Comment: OK, this works for create, because there are IDs for JobDetail to reference, but what about `after(:build)`? Any way to have associations for unsaved objects? Or should I abandon the idea of things working that way?

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue today and I found a solution. Hope this helps someone.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do

    transient do
      details_count 5 # if details count is not given while creating job, 5 is taken as default count
    end

    factory :job_with_details do
      after(:create) do |job, evaluator|
        (0...evaluator.details_count).each do |i|
          job.details << FactoryGirl.create(:detail)
        end
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

This allows to create a job like this

```
create(:job_with_details) #job created with 5 detail objects
create(:job_with_details, details_count: 3) # job created with 3 detail objects
```

Comment: works great with latest everything as of now (rails 5, rspec 3.5, factorygirl 4.8)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do

    # ... Do whatever with the job attributes here

    factory :job_with_detail do

      # In later (as of this writing, unreleased) versions of FactoryGirl
      # you will need to use `transitive` instead of `ignore` here
      ignore do
        detail { create :detail }
      end

      after :create do |job, evaluator|
        job.details << evaluator.detail
        job.save
        job_detail = job.job_details.where(detail:evaluator.detail).first

        # ... do anything with the JobDetail here

        job_detail.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then later

```
# A Detail object is created automatically and associated with the new Job.
FactoryGirl.create :job_with_detail

# To supply a detail object to be associated with the new Job.
FactoryGirl.create :job_with_detail detail:@detail
```

Comment: I know this is old but I am curious as to what makes this better than the accepted answer here?

Comment: When I read the original answer there wasn't enough information in the example for my liking.  This also adds additional functionality on top of that answer since in you can use `create :job_with_detail` with or without the `detail:@detail` option and if not provided then the detail will be created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since FactoryBot v5, associations preserve build strategy. Associations are the best way to solve this and the [docs have good examples for it](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/893eb67bbbde9d7f482852cc5133b4ab57e34b97/GETTING_STARTED.md#has_many-associations):

```rb
FactoryBot.define :job do
  job_details { [association(:job_detail)] }
end

FactoryBot.define :detail do
  description "Full Time"
end

FactoryBot.define :job_detail do
  association :job
  association :detail
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in the following way:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :job do
    # job attributes

    factory :job_with_details do
      transient do
        details_count 10 # default number
      end

      after(:create) do |job, evaluator|
        create_list(:details, evaluator.details_count, job: job)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this, you can create a job_with_details, that has options to specify how many details you want.
You can read [this interesting article](https://kolosek.com/factory-girl-associations) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

With the current factory_bot(previously factory_girl) implementation, everything is taken care by the gem, you don't need to create and then push the records inside the jobs.details. All you need is this

```
factory :job do
  ...

  factory :job_with_details do
    transient do
      details_count { 5 }
    end

    after(:create) do |job, evaluator|
      create_list(:detail, evaluator.details_count, jobs: [job])
      job.reload
    end
  end  
end
```

Below code will produce 5 detail jobs

```
 create(:job_with_details)
```