# factory girl has_many through association

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

I am following the accepted answer from here 
    [Factory Girl: How to setup a has_many/through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444878/has-many-through-with-factory-girl)

I have a has_many through association

```
class Therapist < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :clients, dependent: :destroy
has_many :courses, through: :clients
```

On my factory girl code

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :therapist do
    sequence(:first_name) { |n| "John#{n}" }
    sequence(:last_name)  { |n| "Smith#{n}" }

    factory :therapist_with_course do
      after(:create) { |therapist| therapist.courses <<  FactoryGirl.create(:course) }
     end
   end
 end
```

The Course factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    client
  end
end
```

When I run the test I am getting the following error

```
Failure/Error: let(:therapist) { create :therapist_with_course }
 ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection:
   Cannot modify association 'Therapist#courses' because the source reflection class 'Course' is associated to 'Client' via :has_many.
```

Comment: How are the associations defined in the `Course` and `Client` models?

Comment: class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :therapist

Answer (score 4):

First the `therapist` factory should be created and after the creation of therapist is done you are appending the course factory. In your case you `factory :therapist_with_course` has no information about the `therapist`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :therapist do
      # The therapist attributes here
      after(:create) { |therapist| therapist.courses << FactoryGirl.create(:course) }
   end
end
```